How to call bash script or function to return nonnumerical value in another bash script
I got 2 bash scripts:
sc1.sh
#!/bin/bash
function func_name() {
var123="abcd123"
return $var123
}
func_name

script2.sh
#!/bin/bash
var=  <-here I want to have value abcd123

How to do it? I know there is a error in sc1.sh because return requires numeric only.
I want that sc1.sh return/export etc. value like "abd3831d" and in sc2.sh use this value and passes to another variable e.g.:
var=(value of var123 form sc1.sh)

Does this answer your question? How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?

return in bash is not like in other languages where you can return any data you like, it only sets the numerical exit status of the function so that the caller can know if it succeeded or not.

As I mentioned in my first comment to your previous question, and as the [tag:bash] tag instructs - please run your scripts through http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about before posting here.

Does this answer your question? How to return a string value from a Bash function

See BashFAQ/084 (How do I return a string (or large number, or negative number) from a function? "return" only lets me give a number from 0 to 255.).

Scripts and functions in shell produce 2 types of result:

output - e.g. from echo 'foo'.
exit status - i.e. exit 7 from a script or return 7 from a function.

In the calling code you can capture both of those with:

out=$(script_or_function) - captures the output in variable out.
script_or_function; es="$?" - captures the exit status in variable es

Mix and match as you see fit, e.g.:
foo() {
    local out es
    out=$(script_or_function) || {
        es="$?";
        printf 'script_or_function() failed with exit status "%d" and output "%s"\n' "$es" "$out";
        return "$es";
    }
    printf '%s\n' "$out"
}

The fact that functions in shell use the keyword return to set their exit status when scripts use exit for the same purpose is arguably somewhat unfortunate, especially if you're coming from programming in a language like C where ret=func() stores in ret the value of val from func() { ... return val; }, but functions need some way to distinguish between exiting (returning from) the function vs exiting the process they're called from so you just have to put that behind you and understand that shell is not C and so you should not expect shell syntax or semantics to be like Cs.
FWIW having a function call exit, instead of calling return and letting the caller decide to exit or not, is inversion of control (a low level entity making a high level decision) so while it's not the end of the world and there can be reasons to do so, think hard about it if you're considering calling exit from a function.
One way to do what you show in your question would be:
script1:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

func_name() {
    local var123='abcd123'
    printf '%s\n' "$var123"
}
func_name

script2:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var=$(script1)

Unix commands idiomatically don't have suffixes btw which is why I removed .sh from your scripts file names. Having a suffix is yet another example of tight coupling and so bad software since you couldn't re-implement script1.sh as a compiled C program, and conscientiously still call it script.sh so you'd need to rename the script AND find everywhere it's called and change those other scripts too - hopefully it's obvious that that would be "a bad thing".
